# Select binded value on combobox with Angular 2

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

Please tell me how to solve the problems:

I have web application that is connected to database via API. I have form called user-save-component where I can add and edit user. User have 2 roles: admin and user. I want to select correct role while editing user.

user.role have 2 values: "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_USER", I tried several times but don't have idea if I am doing something wrong or it is a bug of Angular2:

html code:

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
               <option value="ROLE_ADMIN" [selected]="user.role =='ROLE_ADMIN'">admin</option>
            <option value="ROLE_USER" [selected]="user.role =='ROLE_USER'">user</option>
            </select>
```

but doesn't matter how I write it, always select 1st item :

```
<option value="ROLE_USER" [selected]="selected">user</option> or

<option value="ROLE_USER" [selected]="true">user</option> or
<option value="ROLE_USER"selected>user</option>
```

Comment: edit question and add component and html code

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your template like

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN" [attr.selected]="user.role =='ROLE_ADMIN'">admin</option>
    <option value="ROLE_USER" [attr.selected]="user.role =='ROLE_USER'">user</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using very simple and static way to play with **`select control`**.
I'd suggest you to go with more **Angular2** way,

**[DEMO : How to use select control in Angular2 with ngFor](https://plnkr.co/edit/DNvl2NeebP7PmCWwcQY9?p=preview)**

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
        <option *ngFor="let val of user" 
                [value]="val.role"
                [attr.selected]="val.role">
                {{val.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

---

```
export class App {
  user=[{role:"ROLE_ADMIN",name:"Admin"},{role:"ROLE_USERR",name:"User"}];

  constructor(){
    this.user.role=this.user[1].role;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `ROLE_ADMIN` to `user.role`, then the select will show it as initial value

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
   <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">admin</option>
   <option value="ROLE_USER">user</option>
</select>
```

or assign it to `selected` and on change assign it to `user.role` yourself.

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="user.role = $event">
   <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">admin</option>
   <option value="ROLE_USER">user</option>
</select>
```